# Enabling Perforce Job Integration in JIRA

Tags: task, jira, jira-plugin, perforce-integrate

I tried enabling Perforce Job Integration in JIRA, I filled in all the fields also changed `Jobspec` in `Perforce`.

```
com.perforce.api.CommitException java.io.IOException: error: Error in job specification.error: Error detected at line 8.error: Syntax error in 'jobs'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you tried to do since you didn't your job specs files + this question is hanging here for a while...

Here are the spec file that I used and worked for me:

```
# A Perforce Spec Specification.
#
#  Updating this form can be dangerous!
#  To update the job spec, see 'p4 help jobspec' for proper directions.
#  Otherwise, see 'p4 help spec'.

Fields:
    101 Job word 32 required
    102 Status select 10 required
    103 User word 32 required
    104 Date date 20 always
    105 Description text 0 required
    110 IssueStatus line 32 optional
    111 URL line 60 optional
    112 Assignee word 32 optional
    113 Project word 32 optional
    114 Priority line 32 optional
    115 Type line 32 optional

Values:
    Status open/suspended/closed

Presets:
    Status open
    User $user
    Date $now
    Description $blank

Comments:
    # A Perforce Job Specification.
    #
    #  Job:         The job name.  'new' generates a sequenced job number.
    #  Status:      Either 'open', 'closed', or 'suspended'. Can be changed.
    #  User:        The user who created the job. Can be changed.
    #  Date:        The date this specification was last modified.
    #  Description: Comments about the job.  Required.
```

Note that all of the fields that were added for the integration to work are **optional**(If I remember right the recommend it to be "**Required**" but optional works for me and sets them optional...)